# In the real number system,the equation $\sqrt{x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}}+\sqrt{x+8-6\sqrt{x-1}}=1$ has how many solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

In the real number system,the equation $\sqrt{x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}}+\sqrt{x+8-6\sqrt{x-1}}=1$ has how many solutions?

I tried shifting the second term to the rhs and squaring.Even after that i'm left with square roots.No idea how to proceed.Help!

Comment: Did you try to square again ?

Comment: @Peter I did but that makes it more complicated.Can't get rid of the square roots.

Comment: use the binomial fomula

Comment: The whole set $x \in [5,10]$ seems to be a solution.

Comment: $$(\sqrt{x-1}-2)^2$$ and $$(\sqrt{x-1}-3)^2$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

Notice that $$x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}=x-1-4\sqrt{x-1}+4=(\sqrt{x-1}-2)^2$$

and

$$x+8-6\sqrt{x-1}=x-1-6\sqrt{x-1}+9=(\sqrt{x-1}-3)^2=(3-\sqrt{x-1})^2$$

After, you can try by cases.

Comment: And a substitution $z=\sqrt{x-1}$ may help clear things too. $\left\lvert z-2\right\rvert+\left\lvert z-3\right\rvert=1$.

Comment: I get 5 and 10.And btw how did you notice it @Mario G ?Is it a common type of problem?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta Everything in between 5 and 10 is also a solution.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta: I think it is a common type problem since I remember two problems where a trick of this sort worked well.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Answer (score 5):

Set $x=z^2+1$. Then:
$$ \sqrt{x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}}+\sqrt{x+3-8\sqrt{x-1}} = \sqrt{(z-2)^2}+\sqrt{(z-3)^2} = |z-2|+|z-3| $$
equals one for every $z\in[2,3]$, hence for every $x\in[5,10]$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I found that to be odd. So the solutions are $x \in [5,10]$. I guess it wouldn't be too hard to formally prove that.

> *Hint: the imaginary parts cancel on this interval.*

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&\sqrt{x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}}+\sqrt{x+8-6\sqrt{x-1}} = 1\\ \implies &\sqrt{(x-1)-4\sqrt{x-1} + 4}+\sqrt{(x-1)-6\sqrt{x-1}+9}=1\\ \implies &\sqrt{(\sqrt{x-1}-2)^2}+\sqrt{(\sqrt{x-1}-3)^2}=1\\ \implies &|\sqrt{x-1}-2| + |\sqrt{x-1}-3| = 1\tag{1}
\end{align}

This calls for casework:

---

**1.** $\quad\sqrt{x-1}\geq 3$

$(1)\implies \sqrt{x-1}-2 + \sqrt{x-1}-3 = 1\implies \sqrt{x-1} = 3\implies x=10$

---

**2.** $\quad 2\leq\sqrt{x-1} < 3$

$(1)\implies \sqrt{x-1}-2 - \sqrt{x-1}+3 = 1\implies 1 = 1$ and thus all $x$ such that $2\leq\sqrt{x-1} < 3$, i.e. $x\in [5,10\rangle$

---

**3.** $\sqrt{x-1} < 2$

$(1)\implies -\sqrt{x-1}+2 - \sqrt{x-1}+3 = 1\implies \sqrt{x-1} = 2 \implies x = 5$, but this $x$ doesn't satisfy our condition 3 (although it does satisfy condition 2, and is already included as a solution)

---

Taking union, we conclude that any $x\in[5,10]$ is a solution to the equation.

Answer (score -1):

$$x+3-4\sqrt{x-1}=x-1+4-4\sqrt{x-1}=(x-1)-4\sqrt{x-1}+4=(\sqrt{x-1}-2)^2$$ Similarly $$x+8-6\sqrt{x-1}=(\sqrt{x-1}-3)^2$$ from which the answer.

It is not an equation but an identity in its domain of definition.This is the reason there are infinitely many solutions and not the expected finite number of them of a true equation with coefficients in a field. For example the "equation"

$$\sqrt[3]\frac{x^3-3x+(x^2-1)\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}+\sqrt[3]\frac{x^3-3x-(x^2-1)\sqrt{x^2-4}}{2}=x$$ has all the reals as solutions.